# Select text input when bootstrap modal open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a input inside of a bootstrap modal. When the modal is opened, I want the input that that is inside the bootstrap modal to be automatically selected.

I have the following code:

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $(this).$("input").select();
})
```

and my modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
         <input type='text' disabled value="test">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, with this code, I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) and then [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus)

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var input = $(this).find("input");  // cache the variable
   input.removeAttr('disabled'); // enable it first, so it can get focus
   input.focus(); // focus it
})
```

and then use `.focus()` to focus the element. There is nothing called `.select()` in jQuery core.

Comment: `show.bs.modal` did not work for me, while `shown.bs.modal` works

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me:

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#modal input[type="text"]')[0].select();
});
```

note the use of `.on('shown.bs.modal')`, not `.on('show.bs.modal')`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var input= $(this).find("input");
   if(input){
       input.removeAttr('disabled');
       input.focus();
   }
})
```

Comment: `if(input)` is always `true` since objects evaluate to true. You should instead use `if(input.length)`

Comment: `show.bs.modal` did not work for me, while `shown.bs.modal` works